# groupby to flatten list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of students which looks like this:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
{
   new Student(){StudentId = 1, StudentName = "Alex", Grade = "FirstGrade", Marks = 98},
   new Student(){StudentId = 1, StudentName = "Alex", Grade = "SecondGrade", Marks = 92},
   new Student(){StudentId = 1, StudentName = "Alex", Grade = "ThirdGrade", Marks = 95},

   new Student(){StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Karen", Grade = "FirstGrade", Marks = 94},
   new Student(){StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Karen", Grade = "SecondGrade", Marks = 95},
   new Student(){StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Karen", Grade = "ThirdGrade", Marks = 94},

   new Student(){StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Nicole", Grade = "FirstGrade", Marks = 91},
   new Student(){StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Nicole", Grade = "SecondGrade", Marks = 99},
   new Student(){StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Nicole", Grade = "ThirdGrade", Marks = 97},
};
```

I want to convert `students` list to `studentReport` list which looks like this:

```
{ StudentId = 1, StudentName = "Alex", FirstGrade = 98, SecondGrade = 92, ThirdGrade = 95},
{ StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Karen", FirstGrade = 94, SecondGrade = 95, ThirdGrade = 94},
{ StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Nicole", FirstGrade = 91, SecondGrade = 99, ThirdGrade = 97}
```

I was able to achieve that using this:

```
var studentReports = students.GroupBy(student => new { student.StudentId, student.StudentName })
        .Select(group => new Report()
        {
          StudentId = group.Key.StudentId,
          StudentName = group.Key.StudentName,
          FirstGrade = group.Where(student => student.Grade == "FirstGrade").FirstOrDefault().Marks,
          SecondGrade = group.Where(student => student.Grade == "SecondGrade").FirstOrDefault().Marks,
          ThirdGrade = group.Where(student => student.Grade == "ThirdGrade").FirstOrDefault().Marks
        });
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: looks exactly the way I would do it, except you really can just group by student.studentId.  You don't need the whole object including studentName

Comment: You can combine `Where(...).FirstOrDefault()` into `FirstOrDefault(student => student.Grade == "FirstGrade")` using [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) with predicate but in general this seems to be the way)

Comment: Also note that `FirstOrDefault` return null so `.Marks` can throw null reference exception so change it to `?.Marks`.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate this possible refactoring:

```
students.GroupBy(x => x.StudentId).Select(GetReport());
```

static func for select:

```
    static Func<IGrouping<int, Student>, Report> GetReport() => group =>
    {
        var report = new Report
        {
            StudentId = group.Key,
            StudentName = group.First().StudentName,
        };

        foreach (var student in group)
            report.SetGrade(student);

        return report;
    };
```

specific report grades "setter":

```
    public class Report
    {
        public void SetGrade(Student student)
        {
            switch (student.Grade)
            {
                case "FirstGrade":
                    FirstGrade = student.Marks; break;
                case "SecondGrade":
                    SecondGrade= student.Marks; break;
                case "ThirdGrade":
                    ThirdGrade= student.Marks; break;
            }
        }
        [...props...]
    }
```